# securely send data from one site to another?

Tags: php, security, php4, data-transfer

I am going to post some data from one website to another website. I need a way for the receiving website to be sure that the data was sent from the sending website and not sent by some other malicious user. I am using PHP4.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: PHP4 has not been supported since the end of 2007. There have been no security fixes for it since then. So this is probably a much larger security problem for than your own code, at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For a PHP-only solution:**

If you can keep a secret (on both ends), then you can use a self-implemented variant (yes, a variant) of [Keyed-Hash Message Authentication Code (HMAC or KHMAC).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)

The concept is that if you have the same secret on both ends, you can hash (message+secret) on the sending end, and hash (message+secret) on the recieving end.  If the hashes match, then you have a valid message.

The secret is the key (pun intended).  Because without the secret, it is infeasible that an attacker could alter the message AND generate a new hash that will verify on the receiving end.

**Here is some example PHP code:**

```
// On the sending end:
define('SECRET', '12734981273912379128739128739127938794729327492');
$message = 'your-message';
$packet = $message . sha1($message . SECRET);

// On the receiving end:
define('SECRET', '12734981273912379128739128739127938794729327492');
$message = substr($packet, 0, -40);
if(sha1($message . SECRET) != substr($packet, -40))
    throw new Exception("Message Authentication failed!")
else
    do_something_with($message);
```

If you wanted additional security from a hacker re-posting the same message, you could add a random request identifier to each request, and ensure that the same hash is NEVER accepted.

**DISCLAIMER: this as with all security sensitive code should be peer reviewed and verified before being trusted with sensitive data.  Do through research on the topic, or better yet, use an existing library that handles this type of verification+authentication.**

Comment: another disclaimer: this sends the information publicly, although it does do as requested and prevent injection

Answer (score 3):

Just use two-way ssl. The client authenticates itself at the server with a ssl certificate not only the other way around.

So the server knows it's the right client he gets the data form.

The client knows he sends the data to the right server

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

jitter's solution (bidirectional SSL) works.  However, a possibly simpler way is to use one-way SSL (authenticate receiving server) and Basic Auth.  SSL provides confidentiality and Basic Auth authenticates the client.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using GnuPG: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1265

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for SSL, but as an alternative.

If both sites know a secret key (SK) then,

1. website1 (WS1) can send website2 (WS2) a nonce (N1)
2. WS2 can send WS1 a message that contains:

   - the data (could be encrypted using the secret key)
   - md5(SK . N1) (i.e. proof that WS2 knows SK)
   - md5(SK . data) (i.e. proof that the data was not manipulated by a third party